# How to enable webview cookies?

Tags: flutter

[image: screenshot of my error]I am trying to implement payment gateway called "cow pay" in my flutter app using webview but I always get this error. Here is my code:

```
          WebView(
             initialUrl:
                  "my url",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              },
              onPageStarted: (String url) {
                print('Page started loading: $url');
              },
              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                print('Page finished loading: $url');

              },
              gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use evaluateJavascript function

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
            _controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
          },
```

Comment: It didn't work. This error appears to me: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document."

Comment: See this article https://fidev.io/stripe-in-flutter-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `initialUrl: "my url",`

Also, use **webview_cookie_manager** plugin

```
WebView(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async{
        _controller = webViewController;
        await cookieManager.setCookies([
          Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
            ..domain = domain
            ..expires = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1))
            ..httpOnly = false
        ]);
        _controller.loadUrl("your URL");

      },
      )
```